# All my dropdown menus (in applications and right click) work, but are invisible in AwesomeWM

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, awesome-wm

The title is self explanatory... I was configuring AwesomeWM and suddenly realised that none of my dropdown menus were working (they were working fine before). Actually, I noticed that they were working, but are completely invisible. This happens in application menus (like the top menu on pcmanfm) and in desktop, when I right click. For example, in Notepadqq, if click on the Search menu on the top, nothing appears, but I can move down the mouse, left click, and the search tool appears; the same occurs in desktop, where I can can right click and nothing will show up, but moving the mouse to where the apps would appear and left clicking, the selected app opens. The menu is there, I can click stuff, but I don't know what I'm clicking. The only one that is normal is Vivaldi's menu. I really don't know what I did to cause that, and would appreciate any help.

I don't think there's something wrong with my `rc.lua` file, but here is a part of it:

```
-- {{{ Required libraries

-- If LuaRocks is installed, make sure that packages installed through it are
-- found (e.g. lgi). If LuaRocks is not installed, do nothing.
pcall(require, "luarocks.loader")

local gears         = require("gears")
local awful         = require("awful")
                      require("awful.autofocus")
local wibox         = require("wibox")
local beautiful     = require("beautiful")
local naughty       = require("naughty")
local lain          = require("lain")
local vicious       = require("vicious")

--local menubar       = require("menubar")
local freedesktop   = require("freedesktop")
local hotkeys_popup = require("awful.hotkeys_popup")
                      require("awful.hotkeys_popup.keys")
local mytable       = awful.util.table or gears.table -- 4.{0,1} compatibility

-- }}}

-- {{{ Error handling

-- Check if awesome encountered an error during startup and fell back to
-- another config (This code will only ever execute for the fallback config)
if awesome.startup_errors then
    naughty.notify {
        preset = naughty.config.presets.critical,
        title = "Oops, there were errors during startup!",
        text = awesome.startup_errors
    }
end

-- Handle runtime errors after startup
do
    local in_error = false

    awesome.connect_signal("debug::error", function (err)
        if in_error then return end

        in_error = true

        naughty.notify {
            preset = naughty.config.presets.critical,
            title = "Oops, an error happened!",
            text = tostring(err)
        }

        in_error = false
    end)
end

-- }}}

-- {{{ Autostart windowless processes

-- This function will run once every time Awesome is started
local function run_once(cmd_arr)
    for _, cmd in ipairs(cmd_arr) do
        awful.spawn.with_shell(string.format("pgrep -u $USER -fx '%s' > /dev/null || (%s)", cmd, cmd))
    end
end

run_once({ "urxvtd", "unclutter -root" }) -- comma-separated entries

-- This function implements the XDG autostart specification
--[[
awful.spawn.with_shell(
    'if (xrdb -query | grep -q "^awesome\\.started:\\s*true$"); then exit; fi;' ..
    'xrdb -merge <<< "awesome.started:true";' ..
    -- list each of your autostart commands, followed by ; inside single quotes, followed by ..
    'dex --environment Awesome --autostart --search-paths "$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/autostart:$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/autostart"' -- https://github.com/jceb/dex
)
--]]

-- }}}

-- {{{ Variable definitions

local themes = {
    "blackburn",       -- 1
    "copland",         -- 2
    "dremora",         -- 3
    "holo",            -- 4
    "multicolor",      -- 5
    "powerarrow",      -- 6
    "powerarrow-dark", -- 7
    "rainbow",         -- 8
    "steamburn",       -- 9
    "vertex"           -- 10
}

local chosen_theme = themes[7]
local modkey       = "Mod4"
local altkey       = "Mod1"
local terminal     = "/home/daniel/.local/kitty.app/bin/kitty"
local vi_focus     = false -- vi-like client focus https://github.com/lcpz/awesome-copycats/issues/275
local cycle_prev   = true  -- cycle with only the previously focused client or all https://github.com/lcpz/awesome-copycats/issues/274
local editor       = os.getenv("EDITOR") or "vim"
local browser      = "vivaldi"
local brightness_widget = require("awesome-wm-widgets.brightness-widget.brightness")

awful.util.terminal = terminal
awful.util.tagnames = { "main", "www", "files", "dev", "other" }
awful.layout.layouts = {
    awful.layout.suit.tile,
    awful.layout.suit.max,
    awful.layout.suit.fair,
    awful.layout.suit.tile.bottom,
    awful.layout.suit.tile.top,
    --awful.layout.suit.fair,
    --awful.layout.suit.fair.horizontal,
    --awful.layout.suit.spiral,
    --awful.layout.suit.spiral.dwindle,
    --awful.layout.suit.max,
    --awful.layout.suit.max.fullscreen,
    --awful.layout.suit.magnifier,
    --awful.layout.suit.corner.nw,
    --awful.layout.suit.corner.ne,
    --awful.layout.suit.corner.sw,
    --awful.layout.suit.corner.se,
    --lain.layout.cascade,
    --lain.layout.cascade.tile,
    --lain.layout.centerwork,
    --lain.layout.centerwork.horizontal,
    --lain.layout.termfair,
    --lain.layout.termfair.center
}

lain.layout.termfair.nmaster           = 3
lain.layout.termfair.ncol              = 1
lain.layout.termfair.center.nmaster    = 3
lain.layout.termfair.center.ncol       = 1
lain.layout.cascade.tile.offset_x      = 2
lain.layout.cascade.tile.offset_y      = 32
lain.layout.cascade.tile.extra_padding = 5
lain.layout.cascade.tile.nmaster       = 5
lain.layout.cascade.tile.ncol          = 2

awful.util.taglist_buttons = mytable.join(
    awful.button({ }, 1, function(t) t:view_only() end),
    awful.button({ modkey }, 1, function(t)
        if client.focus then client.focus:move_to_tag(t) end
    end),
    awful.button({ }, 3, awful.tag.viewtoggle),
    awful.button({ modkey }, 3, function(t)
        if client.focus then client.focus:toggle_tag(t) end
    end),
    awful.button({ }, 4, function(t) awful.tag.viewnext(t.screen) end),
    awful.button({ }, 5, function(t) awful.tag.viewprev(t.screen) end)
)

awful.util.tasklist_buttons = mytable.join(
     awful.button({ }, 1, function(c)
         if c == client.focus then
             c.minimized = true
         else
             c:emit_signal("request::activate", "tasklist", { raise = true })
         end
     end),
     awful.button({ }, 3, function()
         awful.menu.client_list({ theme = { width = 250 } })
     end),
     awful.button({ }, 4, function() awful.client.focus.byidx(1) end),
     awful.button({ }, 5, function() awful.client.focus.byidx(-1) end)
)

beautiful.init(string.format("%s/.config/awesome/themes/%s/theme.lua", os.getenv("HOME"), chosen_theme))

-- }}}

-- Net widget creation
local net_speed_widget = require("awesome-wm-widgets.net-speed-widget.net-speed")

-- To-do widget
local todo_widget = require("awesome-wm-widgets.todo-widget.todo")

local spotify_widget = require("awesome-wm-widgets.spotify-widget.spotify")

-- {{{ Menu

-- Create a launcher and a main menu
local myawesomemenu = {
   { "Hotkeys", function() hotkeys_popup.show_help(nil, awful.screen.focused()) end },
   { "Manual", string.format("%s -e man awesome", terminal) },
   { "Edit config", string.format("%s -e %s %s", terminal, editor, awesome.conffile) },
   { "Restart", awesome.restart },
   { "Quit", function() awesome.quit() end },
}

awful.util.mymainmenu = freedesktop.menu.build {
    before = {
        { "Awesome", myawesomemenu, beautiful.awesome_icon },
        -- other triads can be put here
    },
    after = {
        { "Open terminal", terminal },
        -- other triads can be put here
    }
}

-- Hide the menu when the mouse leaves it
--[[
awful.util.mymainmenu.wibox:connect_signal("mouse::leave", function()
    if not awful.util.mymainmenu.active_child or
       (awful.util.mymainmenu.wibox ~= mouse.current_wibox and
       awful.util.mymainmenu.active_child.wibox ~= mouse.current_wibox) then
        awful.util.mymainmenu:hide()
    else
        awful.util.mymainmenu.active_child.wibox:connect_signal("mouse::leave",
        function()
            if awful.util.mymainmenu.wibox ~= mouse.current_wibox then
                awful.util.mymainmenu:hide()
            end
        end)
    end
end)
--]]

-- Set the Menubar terminal for applications that require it
--menubar.utils.terminal = terminal

-- }}}

-- {{{ Screen

-- Re-set wallpaper when a screen's geometry changes (e.g. different resolution)
screen.connect_signal("property::geometry", function(s)
    -- Wallpaper
    if beautiful.wallpaper then
        local wallpaper = beautiful.wallpaper
        -- If wallpaper is a function, call it with the screen
        if type(wallpaper) == "function" then
            wallpaper = wallpaper(s)
        end
        gears.wallpaper.maximized(wallpaper, s, true)
    end
end)

-- No borders when rearranging only 1 non-floating or maximized client
screen.connect_signal("arrange", function (s)
    local only_one = #s.tiled_clients == 1
    for _, c in pairs(s.clients) do
        if only_one and not c.floating or c.maximized or c.fullscreen then
            c.border_width = 0
        else
            c.border_width = beautiful.border_width
        end
    end
end)

-- Create a wibox for each screen and add it
awful.screen.connect_for_each_screen(function(s) beautiful.at_screen_connect(s) end)

-- }}}

-- {{{ Mouse bindings

root.buttons(mytable.join(
    awful.button({ }, 3, function () awful.util.mymainmenu:toggle() end),
    awful.button({ }, 4, awful.tag.viewnext),
    awful.button({ }, 5, awful.tag.viewprev)
))

-- }}}

-- Set keys
root.keys(globalkeys)

-- }}}

-- {{{ Rules

-- Rules to apply to new clients (through the "manage" signal).
awful.rules.rules = {
    -- All clients will match this rule.
    { rule = { },
      properties = { border_width = beautiful.border_width,
                     border_color = beautiful.border_normal,
                     focus = awful.client.focus.filter,
                     raise = true,
                     keys = clientkeys,
                     buttons = clientbuttons,
                     screen = awful.screen.preferred,
                     placement = awful.placement.no_overlap+awful.placement.no_offscreen,
                     size_hints_honor = false
                    }
     },
    
    
    { rule = { class = "x-terminal-emulator" },
        properties = { opacity = 0.9 } },
        

    -- Floating clients.
    { rule_any = {
        instance = {
          "DTA",  -- Firefox addon DownThemAll.
          "copyq",  -- Includes session name in class.
          "pinentry",
        },
        class = {
          "Arandr",
          "Blueman-manager",
          "Gpick",
          "Kruler",
          "MessageWin",  -- kalarm.
          "Sxiv",
          "Tor Browser", -- Needs a fixed window size to avoid fingerprinting by screen size.
          "Wpa_gui",
          "veromix",
          "xtightvncviewer"},

        -- Note that the name property shown in xprop might be set slightly after creation of the client
        -- and the name shown there might not match defined rules here.
        name = {
          "Event Tester",  -- xev.
        },
        role = {
          "AlarmWindow",  -- Thunderbird's calendar.
          "ConfigManager",  -- Thunderbird's about:config.
          "pop-up",       -- e.g. Google Chrome's (detached) Developer Tools.
        }
      }, properties = { floating = true }},

    -- Add titlebars to normal clients and dialogs
    { rule_any = {type = { "normal", "dialog" }
      }, properties = { titlebars_enabled = true }
    },

    -- Set Firefox to always map on the tag named "2" on screen 1.
     { rule = { class = "Vivaldi" },
       properties = { screen = 1, tag = "www" } },
}

-- }}}

-- {{{ Signals

-- Signal function to execute when a new client appears.
client.connect_signal("manage", function (c)
    -- Set the windows at the slave,
    -- i.e. put it at the end of others instead of setting it master.
    -- if not awesome.startup then awful.client.setslave(c) end

    if awesome.startup
      and not c.size_hints.user_position
      and not c.size_hints.program_position then
        -- Prevent clients from being unreachable after screen count changes.
        awful.placement.no_offscreen(c)
    end
end)

--[[
-- Add a titlebar if titlebars_enabled is set to true in the rules.
client.connect_signal("request::titlebars", function(c)
    -- Custom
    if beautiful.titlebar_fun then
        beautiful.titlebar_fun(c)
        return
    end

    -- Default
    -- buttons for the titlebar
    local buttons = mytable.join(
        awful.button({ }, 1, function()
            c:emit_signal("request::activate", "titlebar", {raise = true})
            awful.mouse.client.move(c)
        end),
        awful.button({ }, 3, function()
            c:emit_signal("request::activate", "titlebar", {raise = true})
            awful.mouse.client.resize(c)
        end)
    )

    awful.titlebar(c, { size = 16 }) : setup {
        { -- Left
            awful.titlebar.widget.iconwidget(c),
            buttons = buttons,
            layout  = wibox.layout.fixed.horizontal
        },
        { -- Middle
            { -- Title
                align  = "center",
                widget = awful.titlebar.widget.titlewidget(c)
            },
            buttons = buttons,
            layout  = wibox.layout.flex.horizontal
        },
        { -- Right
            awful.titlebar.widget.floatingbutton (c),
            awful.titlebar.widget.maximizedbutton(c),
            awful.titlebar.widget.stickybutton   (c),
            awful.titlebar.widget.ontopbutton    (c),
            awful.titlebar.widget.closebutton    (c),
            layout = wibox.layout.fixed.horizontal()
        },
        layout = wibox.layout.align.horizontal
    }
end) ]]--

-- Enable sloppy focus, so that focus follows mouse.
client.connect_signal("mouse::enter", function(c)
    c:emit_signal("request::activate", "mouse_enter", {raise = vi_focus})
end)

client.connect_signal("focus", function(c) c.border_color = beautiful.border_focus end)
client.connect_signal("unfocus", function(c) c.border_color = beautiful.border_normal end)

-- }}}

-- Autostart Applications
--awful.spawn.with_shell("compton")
awful.util.spawn("nm-applet")
awful.spawn.with_shell("nitrogen --restore")

-- Add gaps between tiles
beautiful.useless_gap = 2
```

Comment: Do you use a compositing manager like `compton` or `picom`? If so, do the problem happens without it. If not, is the problem solved by using one? I am just trying to rule out drivers wierdness first.

Comment: I use compton. I think you solve the mistery. When I comment the line awful.spawn.with_shell("compton") in rc.lua and reboot (restart Awesome doesn't work), the menus started to work again. I can live without it, but I used compton to add opacity to the terminal.

Comment: You might want to try `picom`, it is less buggy than `compton`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out!

Comment: Cool. I posted a "real" answer below so future viewers can see it (and because this is a stackoverflow policy), please accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably due to using a compositing manager like compton or picom. You can either try another compositing manager, update your graphics driver.

You can also try to start Awesome with `--no-argb`. This will disable some features like true transparency in the titlebars, but is closer to what other window manager use, so tends to trigger less bugs in the graphics driver or compositing managers.